# Taking the address of an overloaded function template

Tags: c++, templates

I have a function template `getDescriptor` with two overloads. They have the following signatures:

```
template <class _DescriptorType>
typename _DescriptorType::FeatureType getDescriptor
(const View & view, const _DescriptorType & desc);
```

and

```
template <class _DescriptorType>
typename _DescriptorType::FeatureType getDescriptor
(const Instance & instance, const _DescriptorType & desc);
```

I have a different function template `getEncoding` in which I need the address of the first `getDescriptor` function, with the `_DescriptorType` from `getEncoding`:

```
template <class _DescriptorType>
Encoding getEncoding()
{
    auto ptr = static_cast<...>(getDescriptor);

    ...
}
```

What do I need to put in the `static_cast` to get the address of the second overloaded `getDescriptor` template, with the `_DescriptorType` set to the one of `getEncoding`?

Comment: Notes: (1) name starting with underscore followed by uppercase, is reserved to the implementation, (2) both overloads seem to return `FeatureType` but yet they're called `getDescriptor`, (3) also client code might get into the overload problem you have, so why not just call this functions different things, e.g. `featureFromView` versus `featureFromInstance`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go :

```
auto ptr = static_cast<
    typename _DescriptorType::FeatureType (*)(const Instance &, const _DescriptorType &)
>(getDescriptor<_DescriptorType>);
```